# Redux-Thunk to Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-saga

im trying to passs some calls to redux-saga from redux-thunk im getting some error , im new on saga so here the codes examples from the 2 funcions from saga and below are what im tring to do if some one can help me it will be a great help

```
var LOAD_TRANSLATIONS = exports.LOAD_TRANSLATIONS = 'loadTranslation';
// redux-thunk
var loadTranslations = exports.loadTranslations = function   loadTranslations(translations) {
 return function (dispatch) {
     _index.I18n.forceComponentsUpdate();
     dispatch({
         type: LOAD_TRANSLATIONS,
         translations: translations
     });
  };
 };

// saga
function* loadTranslations() {
    const lang = yield take(LOAD_TRANSLATIONS);
    yield fork(getLang, lang);
}

function* getLang(lang){
    console.log(lang);
    yield put({
        type: LOAD_TRANSLATIONS,
    translations: lang
 });
}


// redux-thunk
var SET_LOCALE = exports.SET_LOCALE = 'setLocal';

var setLocale = exports.setLocale = function setLocale(locale) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    _index.I18n.forceComponentsUpdate();
    dispatch({
      type: SET_LOCALE,
      locale: locale
    });
  };
};


//saga
function* setLocale() {
 const locale = yield take(SET_LOCALE);
 yield fork(getLocale, locale);
}

function* getLocale(locale){
 console.log(locale);
 _index.I18n.forceComponentsUpdate();
 yield put({
     type: SET_LOCALE,
     locale: locale
 });
}
```

Comment: Could you please paste how you registered your saga middleware?

Comment: The saga would look like this


    ```function* setLocale(){
        yield takeEvery(SET_LOCALE, getLocale)
    }
```
the action is passed into the `getLocale` generator function.

Take a look at the example from the home page https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `takeEvery` which takes two params, the action constant and the generator to run. So your example might look like this

```
function* setLocale(){
    yield takeEvery(SET_LOCALE, getLocale)
}
# you could use takeEvery or takeLatest
```

and the getLocale gets the action being passed

```
function* getLocale(action){
    console.log(action);
    _index.I18n.forceComponentsUpdate();
     yield put({
        type: SET_LOCALE,
        locale: action.locale
     });
```

You could check the first example on https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Actions dispatched in sagas will trigger sagas.

Meaning this will likely cause an infinite loop or just don't work.

You have to use (unfortunately) different action types for triggering sagas and triggering the reducer from a saga.